# How to extract firmware from a chip ( snarfing)

Tags: disassemblers, binary-editing

Is there anyone who can guide me how do i do snarfing of firmware on a chip of a VIN Tuner.

Is there anyone who can do it ?

Comment: what exactly is "snarfing"? Some references might help.

Comment: Snarfing means eating fast with great appetite ... Totally, out of context here. Maybe @vrickson meant sniffing or extracting.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I think he meant this sort of snarf: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarfing

Comment: @ElianKamal thanks, I didn't know this term

Comment: With all due respect, I believe the question should be re-opened. Sometimes the generic questions, like this one are priceless to solve problems

Answer (score 4):

1. Get the information about the chip. It may happen that firmware, that you need is stored in the external flash memory chip, not in CPU.
2. If it's still the CPU, that you want to dump, read the datasheet for the chip to learn how it's programmed and which hardware you need to connect to the chip (JTAG atapter most probably)
3. Find if there are 'test points' on the PCB, which lead to the programming interface pins of the chip
4. If there are no such 'test points' desolder the chip, and solder it to your own PCB where you have all necessary pins connected.
5. Connect JTAG adapter to the appropriate pins
6. Use the software which is designed to work with such chips via JTAG to read the firmware or SRAM.
7. Most likely the chip will have the protection enabled, so that you won't be able to read the firmware, so you'll have to overcome that using various techniques.

Here's the example: http://blog.includesecurity.com/2015/11/NordicSemi-ARM-SoC-Firmware-dumping-technique.html